# Response not sucessful:Recevied status code 500 using apolloclient graphql reactNative

Tags: react-native, graphql

```
when put token value as hardcoded it's work properly,but when i got token from asyncstorage and pass token in headers i got this error
Response not sucessful:Recevied status code 500 What is wrong in mycode?


import { ApolloClient,ApolloProvider,InMemoryCache,gql } from '@apollo/client'
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client'
 const getToken = async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
  return token
}
const token = getToken()
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createUploadLink({
    uri: 'http://192.168.1.82:8080/graphql',
    headers: {
      authorization: token
    }
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

When I add authorizan in headers I got this Error:Response not sucessful:Received status code 500 In React native otherwise it's work perfectly . What is issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try then function for async function

```
getToken().then((token) => {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: createUploadLink({
      uri: 'http://192.168.1.82:8080/graphql',
      headers: {
        authorization: token
      }
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
});
```

Comment: I update my code still same error occur..

Comment: when write console.log token before 'const client = new ApolloClient', what do you see?